# Trouble operating on my pandas dataframe in a loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, memory, in-place

I am trying to loop through a list that contains two pandas data frames:

```
dataset = [df_train, df_test]

for df in dataset:
    df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['A', 'B','C'])
```

I was expecting this to give me updated versions of *df_train* and *df_test* with the dummy variables included, however it leaves them unchanged.
When I check *df* it is the expected updated *df_test* with the dummy variables. I am guessing this is something to do with Pythons memory allocation and only referencing the variable or something like that?

I also tried the following but to the same result:

```
for df in dataset:
    df = pd.get_dummies(df.copy(), columns=['A', 'B','C'])
```

I also tried without success:

```
for i in range(len(dataset)):
    df = dataset[i]
    dataset[i] = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['A', 'B','C'])
```

I currently have a workaround which is:

```
df_train = pd.get_dummies(df_train, columns=['A', 'B','C'])
df_test = pd.get_dummies(df_test, columns=['A', 'B','C'])
```

This is fine because I only have two dataframes but I would like to know what I am missing about what python is doing that prevents me overwriting *df* but not *df_train*  and *df_test*.

I had no problem doing similar operations elsewhere in my code so long as I had *inplace=True* set, e.g.

```
for df in dataset:
    df.drop('A', axis=1, inplace = True)
```

The code above ran fine which I can only assume has to do with the fact that its working inplace. This seems like a python memory thing? Can anyone explain please?

Answer (score 1):

You are right that with your current method(s), you aren't modifying the DataFrame but rather its reference, whereas with a method like `.drop`, this particular method does modify the actual DataFrame. I think you can combine your two methods by making a copy of the ith element of the dataset.

```
for i in range(len(dataset)):
    dataset[i] = pd.get_dummies(dataset[i].copy(), columns=['A','B','C'])
```

Answer (score 0):

`df` is a reference to the DataFrame. When you use method `.drop()` you are making a modification to the reference and therefore to the original DataFrame. When you are performing `pd.get_dummies()` on the `df` and assigning it to a new `df` you are just changing what the reference is referring to the DataFrame.